# Why does Scrapy not provide a response object?

Tags: python, scrapy

I use the Scrapy Shell and use the following command:

```
scrapy shell https://www.off---white.com/en/DE/men/t/seasons/ss-2020
```

There is no error message, but the response object is of type None and I have no idea why. I ask for help!

Comment: Hey, that is very strange -did you give it try with other site?

Comment: Yes, I did. On other sites it works without problems. I have seen during debugging that very often a redirect to another page is made (about 10 times) and at the end the redirect is aborted because of "maximum number of redirects reached". It is just not considered an error.

Answer (score 0):

@Toobi77

It sounds like prevention from **scraping** by unknown devices. You should add header to the request you make to this site. I tried to search at documentation, if the header can be added by CLI, but it seems to be, that it's not.

Just open the scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell
```

And then make request manually:

```py
>>> from scrapy import Request
>>> my_header = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36',
    # some other here
    }
>>> req = Request('yoururl.com', headers=my_header)
>>> fetch(req)
```

This will update you shell with current request.